# 50-amp inlet able to be used with 30-amp generator via adapter?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, generator

I'm thinking of putting in an inlet box so as to be able to use a generator if the power goes out (with interlock too for safety).

I'm not sure what generator I'm going to get yet, but would like to be able to have the option to either get one that has a 50A or 30A as its max output.

To keep both options open, can I just put in a 50 amp inlet and then get some sort of adapter to enable a 30 amp plug of a lesser generator to work with it, or is there something about phases / voltage / etc. which would make this not an option?

EDIT - if anyone reads about bonded/floating neutral generators below and has additional questions, I came across this page which goes into a pretty lengthy explanation https://generatorbible.com/blog/bonded-neutral-vs-floating-neutral/

Comment: Is it OK if this generator's dedicated to backup power for your house, or do you want to be able to take it on the road with you as well?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I could see occasions when I'd like to bring it on the road (though not common), but I'd be interested in understanding the implications of the question if you don't mind elaborating.  At a minimum I'd like to be able to keep it indoors and only put it out at the inlet when needed.  Thanks

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I found with mine it was a 2-minute exercise to switch from bonded to floating neutral.  I don't plan to use it as portable but if I do it would take 1 minute the second time.   It has no GFCI on the 220V outlets.   I was worried about if the chassis might be used as a neutral path for any of the on-board electronics so I looked carefully, checked the circuit diagram, and found that the chassis is in fact used as Common for the 12V side of things but not for anything else.  To my pleasant surprise the battery charger has its own coils in the stator so not connected to 120V!

Comment: @jay613 -- yeah, it's fairly easy to convert some models at least (although many don't really talk about this in their documentation for some odd reason)

Answer (score 3):

### Most generators that support 50A plugs also support 30A plugs as well

Many (most?) portable generators with a high enough wattage rating to support a 50A (14-50R or CS6365) receptacle also have a 30A (L14-30R) receptacle that can be used instead, so I would fit a 30A inlet box to your house if I were in your shoes.

### Don't let your generator hopes get *neutral*-ized!

However, if you want to use your generator as both a standby generator and as a portable power source, you'll need to be careful when setting up your standby power system.  This is because generators meant for portable use (especially contractor/industrial grade generators) often have a *bonded neutral*, and some have GFCI protection on their 30 and 50A receptacles as well.  If you were to try to use such a generator with an interlock kit or solid neutral transfer switch, you'd cause untold mayhem due to the fact you just put your generator's neutral-ground bond in parallel with your house's.  This situation of dueling neutral-ground bonds leads to objectionable stray current on grounding wires and will trip the GFCI on a generator with full-panel GFCI protection, even.

As a result, you'll have to jettison the interlock kit approach in favor of a *switching neutral* transfer switch or panel.  These aren't as common as interlocks or solid-neutral switches, but are made by Eaton (CHGENxxxxxSN models) and Reliance Controls (their Panel/Link X-series -- the regular Panel/Link units have a solid neutral), and combine a special switching neutral transfer interlock with panel spaces for standby loads.

Comment: Thanks! After reading your reply, I was looking at various options and all I've found are hundreds of dollars across both Eaton and Reliance. Does that seem realistic or am I maybe not finding the right ones?  Btw, in case it's helpful to know, it looks like our main breaker panel which connects to the street is rated for 200A ("GE Power Mark Gold Load Center").  Maybe that's just the price to pay to do it properly as this sounds important, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Hundreds of dollars for what?  If you are installing a 30A inlet, a short length of 10ga cable, a 2 pole 30A breaker, an interlock kit for your panel, and assorted bits of conduit, connectors, etc ... the whole affair should cost less than $300.  There's another option called a "load side transfer switch", that would add another $200 or so and in some circumstances may be helpful.

Comment: @jay613 -- switching neutral transfer panels are sadly a fair bit more costly than an interlock kit, usually running $200-$300 by themselves (similar to a loadside transfer switch)

Comment: @g491 -- you should be able to get one of the new-line Panel/Link X-series models for $200-$300 or so worst-case, and the rest of the parts (inlet box, 10/3, 30A breaker for your panel) should be a pittance in comparison

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel if I buy a generator which is floating neutral, then I shouldn't need a switching neutral panel / transfer switch, correct? Thanks

Comment: @g491 -- that is correct, buying a floating neutral generator lets you use a regular breaker panel fitted with an interlock kit instead of the switching neutral transfer panel.  However, it also means you can't safely use that generator for portable applications

Comment: Ah, so is that why the manual for it says you have to stick a copper rod into the ground and attach to that? @ThreePhaseEel

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question, ignoring the many other worthwhile discussions that must be had, is yes.  If you install a 50A inlet and buy a 30A generator you can use a suitable cable to plug it in.

My generator's max output is 31A.  It has both 30A and 50A outlets.  The 50A outlet can deliver 31A.    If you install a 50A inlet and decide to buy a smaller generator you could look for something like mine and then just buy a normal 50A cable to the generator's 50A outlet, to benefit from the generator's max capacity, whatever it is.

If you buy a generator that is exactly 30A or less it may not have the right outlet so you'll need a special cable.  I'd get a cable with suitable ends rather than an extra "adapter" in order to avoid multiple chunky twist-lock heads dangling from my generator or inlet.

Comment: Also do lots of research on the topic raised in the other answer about neutrals.  It's worth understanding that before you buy all your kit.